# Value assigned by List, Changes at every iteration

Tags: list, flutter, dart

This is a function of grouping events by their day. It starts with a `List<EventK>` which contains all the elements to sort. The result is a `Map<DateTime, List<EventK>>`.

The problem is with `currentDayEvents`. Once it is assigned to `_events`, and the value of `currentDayEvents` changes in different iterations, the value of `_events` also changes. How can I get the permanent value of `_events` outside the function?

```
void _getEvents()async{

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    List<EventK> events = await EventApi.getPersonalEvents();
    List<EventK> currentDayEvents = [];

    DateTime currentDay;

    for(int i = 0; i<events.length-1; i++){

      currentDay = events[i].startTime;
      currentDayEvents.add(events[i]);

      for(int j=i+1; j<events.length; j++){

        DateTime analyzedDay = events[j].startTime;

        if(currentDay.year == analyzedDay.year &&
            currentDay.month == analyzedDay.month &&
            currentDay.day == analyzedDay.day
        ){
          currentDayEvents.add(events[j]);
          events.removeAt(j);
          j -= 1;
        }

      }

      _events.putIfAbsent(currentDay, ()=>currentDayEvents);
      currentDayEvents.clear();

    }

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the declaration of `currentDayEvents` inside the for-loop to reinitialise a new object on each iteration. In doing so, you can remove `currentDayEvents.clear()`.

```
for(int i = 0; i<events.length-1; i++){

  currentDay = events[i].startTime;
  var currentDayEvents = [events[i]];

  for(int j=i+1; j<events.length; j++){

    DateTime analyzedDay = events[j].startTime;

    if(currentDay.year == analyzedDay.year &&
        currentDay.month == analyzedDay.month &&
        currentDay.day == analyzedDay.day
    ){
      currentDayEvents.add(events[j]);
      events.removeAt(j);
      j -= 1;
    }

  }

  _events.putIfAbsent(currentDay, ()=>currentDayEvents);
}
```